# Flutter FCM Push Notification Delivery Status

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I wonder if there is a way I could track fcm push notifications delivery in flutter so I can set a callback and be notified when notification is received by device?

Answer (score 0):

Please upload a bit of your code/ detailed code flow as to how you are achieving push notifications .i.e, from webserver/cloud functions/flutter package. In any of the methods, you receive information on the about failed/delivered msgs as well a Message-ID used as a reference when looking up particular messaging operation

If you rely on a web server, then in order to set callbacks on your web server, you can use the feature of Firebase Cloud messaging [Data export to BigQuery](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/understand-delivery#count-percentage-of-delivered-messages) and apply cloud functions to listen to the undelivered messages in bulk automatically. This however may turn a bit costly on a larger scale.